# Negative object id

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I seem to be getting negative values for `object_id` for some objects. Is this correct? If so, when is a ruby object's `object_id` negative?

Comment: I don't think I ever saw a negative `object_id`. Which Ruby version/implementation? Can you post a snippet of code?

Comment: See [this](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/127161).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/gc.c#L3171 should answer your question in full, technical detail, but ultimately because the object pointer is modified in a variety of ways, then returned as a signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

Integers have odd object_id's, and the other objects use the even object_id's. For this to work, negative integers have (odd) negative object_id's - there is no room elsewhere. The even negative object_id's are free to be used for other objects.